# Slicing/Dicing UI Files

Tags: ios, user-interface, photoshop, uiappearance

Is there a quick/easier way to create the required graphic files for an iOS UI theme (at standard and 2x resolutions) from a PSD such as http://graphicriver.net/theme_previews/2989093-magnanimous-ios-ui-kit-for-mobile-interface?index=6. The only way I know of is to use Photoshop to painstakingly cut the image up, but it will probably take me the best part of a day to do so.

Comment: If it will take too long then don't do it.  There are enough crappy themes out there; the world won't notice.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Slicy](http://macrabbit.com/slicy/) for Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

In Photoshop you can use: from the menu: File/Automate/batch and record actions which you use lots of times. Like save As, to -> PNG and add name @2x to it, enz.

After the recording you are able to edit the Action via menu: Windows/Actions